# highcharts js how to add grid lines without labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, grid, lines

Is there a way to add grids lines in highcharts js chart but without labels between existing lines?

I already have the grids lines with value 1, 2, 3, etc and i would to add lines in 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 etc but without the labels in the axes.

Also i need to calculate the interval (the middle points between steps that maybe different each time).

Comment: Please post some jsfiddle or similar so we can see what you tried, and help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable minor ticks and set it `minorTickInterval` to 0.5.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minorTickInterval

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xxk6qjuh/

Comment: yes thanks but i can't add minorTickInterval later with js

Answer (score 0):

check [yAxis.plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines) to add additional grid lines

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kdr0hsh/) Demo

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],


  },
  yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], //fix labels in yAxis
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#ccc',
      width: 1,
      value: 0.5 //position where line needed
    }, {
      color: '#ccc',
      width: 1,
      value: 1.5
    }, {
      color: '#ccc',
      width: 1,
      value: 2.5
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: still doubt _Also i need to calculate the interval (the middle points between steps that maybe different each time)_ what do you want

Comment: Thanks! I mean that the series are calculated, but i can even calulate the middle line.